# DeRham Cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $p$ and $q$ be two points of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where let $n\geq 1$. Then

$$\dim H^k(\mathbb R^n - p - q) = \begin{cases}0, &\text{ if }k\text{ is not equal to }n-1,\\ 2,&\text{ if }k = n-1.\end{cases}$$

I'm trying to prove this, but I've thought of letting $S = \{p,q\}$ and using the fact that the open set of $\mathbb R^{n+1} - S\times \mathbb{R}^1$ of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ is homologically trivial in all dimensions.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No, but just some extra practice problem

Comment: Can someone please help me on this

Comment: I assume, by your title, that you are doing DR cohomology? If so, state this.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: What do you know about DeRham Cohomology?

Comment: Pretty much, it boiled down to understanding the Mayer Vietoris theorem, and homotopy equivalence theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Mayer-Vietoris with $U = \mathbb R^n - \{p\}, V = \mathbb R^n - \{q\}$.  Then $U \cap V = \mathbb R^n -\{p,q\}$ and $U \cup V = \mathbb R^n$.  Then Mayer-Vietoris gives
$$
H^k(\mathbb R^n) \to H^k(U) \oplus H^k(V) \to H^k(\mathbb R^n - \{p,q\})\to H^{k+1}(\mathbb R^n).
$$
But $H^*(\mathbb R^n)$ is trivial so you get $H^*(\mathbb R^n - \{p,q\}) \simeq H^k(U) \oplus H^k(V)$.  But $U$ and $V$ are homotopic to $S^{n-1}$, giving you the desired result.